# Cite a reference with the possibility of opening an internal pdf file at the right page number

Tags: hyperref, citing, pdf, external-files, href

I want to cite a reference in my document with the possibility of opening this reference, which is stored as a pdf file in my directory, on the right page.

It should look something like this:

> [1, Theorem 2, p. 66]

1. If I click on "1", I should be forwarded to the references at the end of the page.
2. If I click on "Theorem 2, p. 66", then I want to be forwarded to the right page of the pdf file.

I have tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

% this works to get 1.
\cite[Theorem 2, p. 66]{Ana1}

% this works to get 2. (at least with Adobe Reader)
\href[page=66]{./Literatur/Analysis1.pdf}{Theorem 2, p. 66}

% this does not work
\cite[\href[page=66]{./Literatur/Analysis1.pdf}{Theorem 2, p. 66}]{Ana1}

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{TestCitations}

\end{document}
```

This yields the error message:

! Argument of \href  has an extra }.

\par
l.14 ...[\href[page=66]{./Literatur/Analysis1.pdf}
{Theorem 2, p. 66}]{Ana1}
?

Does anyone know a workaround for this problem?

Comment: Try to group the optional argument within braces: `\cite[{\href[page=66]{./Literatur/Analysis1.pdf}{Theorem 2, p. 66}}]{}`